# Problem: How to read a minimum value in the list consisting of objects?

Tags: python, iteration, min

How can I read the minimum value of "price" parameter in the "room_options" list, with n elements of the list. Each list item is an instance of Room class:

```
room_options: (list)
   [0] Room
   [1] Room
   [2] Room
   [3] Room
   ...
   [n] Room

Room:
   price=700
   currency="PLN"
   type="Twin Room"
   dining=True
```

I'd like to read a minimum value with the statement:

```
min(unknown_statement)
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Please mark homework with the [homework] tag.  Then read up on the `min` function and the `key` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min(room_options, key=lambda x: x.price)`

Comment: It should read `lambda`, not `lamda`. Also, it puts out the room with the cheapest price, not the cheapest price itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
min(room.price for room in rooms)
```

EDIT: see comment

Comment: Get rid of the square brackets to avoid building a temporary list.